# Multiple rows with Maximum Values in sql

Tags: sql, select, max, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can anyone help me with the below?

I'm trying to group by the (PO) and by (line) to get the Max of (Quantity) regardless of the value in (type).

I tried to group by PO and line both and it didn't work and showing this

> error: "not group by function".

the data look like:

| po | line | type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 4 | 23 |
| 100 | 1 | 5 | 20 |
| 100 | 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 200 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 200 | 2 | 2 | 15 |

and I would like to get the below result:

| po | line | type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 4 | 23 |
| 100 | 2 | 1 | 40 |
| 200 | 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 200 | 2 | 2 | 15 |

the code:

```
select 
orno "PO NUMBER",
pono "Line",  
oltp "Line Type",
max(qoor) "Quantity"
from 
    table 
group by orno;
```

Comment: use plain text or table markdown to display tables, and please also provide some DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.quantity = (select max(t2.quantity)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.po = t.po and t2.line = t.line
                   );
```

In Oracle, another option is aggregation:

```
select po, line,
       max(type) keep (dense_rank first order by quantity desc) as type,
       max(quantity) as quantity
from t
group by po, line;
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracle's fancy way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.

Comment: thanks a lot!! that's work perfectly with the second option. please clarify to me your code as it has advanced statements